# Copy paste row based on another dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset A and dataset B and want to copy and paste the entire row in dataset A and add as another row in the same dataset based on the ID information of dataset B.

Dataset A:

```
dataA = data.frame(id = as.character(1:10),
    name = c("bob", "ryan", "sean", "brock", "kobe", "andy", "andrew", "stephanie", "emma", "monica"),
    place = c(rep("central",3), rep("western",3), rep("eastern",4)) )
```

Dataset B:

```
id_2 = c('1', '3', '5')
data_2 = data.frame(id_2)
```

The final desired dataset should be like this:

```
dataA = data.frame(
  id = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '1', '3', '5'),
  name = c('bob','ryan','sean','brock','kobe','andy','andrew', 'stephanie',
         'emma','monica','bob','sean','kobe'),
  place = c(rep('central',3),rep('western',3),rep('eastern',4),
          'central','central','western') )
```

Comment: It's better (and shorter) to declare your dataframes with explicit column names: `dfB = data.frame(id=c('1','3','5'))`. If your dataframes don't have column names, let alone consistent names, join'ing becomes a pain.

Comment: *"paste an entire row into a dataset"* = *"concatenate row"* = `rbind()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge data_2 to dataA to get other attributes and then bind rows:

```
library(dplyr)                                  # to use pipe operator

colnames(data_2) = 'id'                         # renaming col name for ease
data_2 %>% merge(dataA) %>% rbind(dataA)        # alt. use: dplyr's inner_join with bind_rows
```

Answer (score 2):

```
rbind(dataA,dataA[data_2$id_2,])

#    id      name   place
# 1   1       bob central
# 2   2      ryan central
# 3   3      sean central
# 4   4     brock western
# 5   5      kobe western
# 6   6      andy western
# 7   7    andrew eastern
# 8   8 stephanie eastern
# 9   9      emma eastern
# 10 10    monica eastern
# 11  1       bob central
# 12  2      ryan central
# 13  3      sean central
```